# React Router, createBrowserRouter loader function causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am implementing loader functions on my browser router. The functions trigger an api which updates a context state value. Updating the state is causing the loader function to run again which initiates an infinite loop.

My browser router:

```
const createRouter = (
  baseRoute: string,
  currentUser: CurrentUser | undefined,
  errorMessage: string,
  getSubmission: (
    appTypeId: string,
    submissionId: string
  ) => Promise<SubmissionDetails | void>,
  isError: boolean
) =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/:appTypeId/:submissionId/:referralMasterId?',
      element: (
        <AppLayout
          name={currentUser?.name || 'User Name Not Found'}
          isError={isError}
          errorMessage={errorMessage}
        />
      ),
      id: 'root',
      loader: ({ params }) => {
        const { appTypeId, referralMasterId, submissionId } =
          params as ReferralParams
        return defaulNewAPIs(
          appTypeId,
          currentUser?.username || 'User Name Not Found',
          submissionId,
          getSubmission
        )
      },
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ])

export const AppRoutes: React.FC<{ baseRoute?: string }> = ({ baseRoute }) => {
  const {
    errorMessage,
    getSubmission,
    isError,
  } = useContext(AppContext) as SelectedContextType
  const currentUser = getCurrentUser()

  return (
    <RouterProvider
      router={createRouter(
        baseRoute ?? '',
        currentUser,
        errorMessage,
        getSubmission,
        isError
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

The important parameters above are the `isError` and `getSubmission` prop. Both of these come from a context file.

```
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('Error')

  function getSubmission(appTypeId: string, submissionId: string) {
    return commonAxios
      .get(
        `/api/GetSubmissionInfo?appTypeId=${appTypeId}&submissionId=${submissionId}`
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error: { message: string }) {
        setIsError(true)
        setErrorMessage(error.message)
        setTimeout(() => setIsError(false), 5000)
      })
  }
```

`getSubmission` has a timeout which toggles the `isError` state after a failed api call.

Finally the implementation of `isError` is on the `AppLayout` component.

```
export const AppLayout: React.FC<{
  name: string
  showHeader?: boolean
  isError: boolean
  errorMessage: string
}> = ({ name, showHeader = true, isError, errorMessage }) => {
  const currentUser = { name: name }

  return (
    <>
      {showHeader && (
        <AppHeader
          appName="REFERRALS"
          currentUser={currentUser}
          showGenStar={true}
          showGenesis={true}
          showNotifications={false}
          // notificationNumber={4}
        />
      )}
      {isError && <MuiAlert severity="error" text={errorMessage} />}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

I am struggling to understand why this is causing an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see it would appear that each time the `AppContext` value updates it should trigger the `AppRoutes` component to rerender, and when this occurs a new router is created when `createRouter` is called. This creates an entirely new router reference, e.g. React will unmount the previous "instance" and mount this new "instance". It's like all the routes load again for the first time, including running any route loaders.

Memoize the router so you are providing a stable reference. I suggest placing the `currentUser` value in a React ref so the ref can be provided also as a stable reference to the routes and loader functions.

```
export const AppRoutes: React.FC<{ baseRoute?: string }> = ({ baseRoute }) => {
  const appContext = useContext(AppContext) as SelectedContextType;

  const appContextRef = React.useRef<SelectedContextType>(appContext);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    appContextRef.current = appContext;
  }, [appContext]);

  const router = React.useMemo(() => {
    return createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: '/:appTypeId/:submissionId/:referralMasterId?',
        element: (
          <AppLayout
            name={getCurrentUser()?.name || 'User Name Not Found'}
            isError={appContextRef.current.isError}
            errorMessage={appContextRef.current.errorMessage}
          />
        ),
        id: 'root',
        loader: ({ params }) => {
          const {
            appTypeId,
            referralMasterId,
            submissionId
          } = params as ReferralParams;

          return defaulNewAPIs(
            appTypeId,
            getCurrentUser()?.username || 'User Name Not Found',
            submissionId,
            appContextRef.current.getSubmission
          );
        },
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ], { basename });
  }, [appContextRef, baseRoute, getCurrentUser]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew! The docs for React Router state that `createBrowserRouter` should be called outside of the React tree. I think the method you are proposing will work but would violate that principle.

Comment: @tdammon It's *just* their recommendation, and a good one, but it's not a rule. Declaring it outside the ReactTree is just an easy way to provide a stable router reference. *Sometimes* though you need it inside the ReactTree so you can close over internal React references, and using the `useMemo` hook allows you to still provide a stable-ish reference.

Comment: It seems to me like this is a bug with `createBrowserRouter`. What value is there in running loader functions if they can't make state updates without triggering an infinite loop.

Comment: @tdammon I think you are misunderstanding the issue, or bug, here. The problem isn't that the router can't handle a loader updating some React state/context value, it's that the router is redeclared each render cycle in `AppRoutes` when you call `router={createRouter(.....)}` for the `RouterProvider` component ***because*** something downstream triggered a rerender. It's not too dissimilar to ***unconditionally*** calling a `setState` function during a component render and creating a render loop.